# Angular upload file without file to backend (400 bad request)

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript

How can I upload file without file to backend

I'm sending null to file in param(doesn't choose file)

Angular:

```
//this.currentFileUpload -> null
this._reportService.createReportTemplate(this.reportTemplate.code, this.reportTemplate.name, this.reportTemplate.status, this.currentFileUpload)
        .subscribe(res => {

            console.log('Save report', res);
        });
```

Angular Service:

```
private httpOptions(): HttpHeaders {
    return new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': token is here // doesn't matter
    });
};


createReportTemplate(templateCode: string, templateName: string, status: string, file: File): Observable<any> {
    const data: FormData = new FormData();

    data.set('file', file);
    return this
        .http
        .post('/address/upload' + templateCode + '&Rname=' + templateName + '&Status=' + status, data, {headers: this.httpOptions()});
}
```

Backend:

```
@PostMapping(value="/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "With upload file")
public CReportTemplates create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               @RequestParam("Code") String code,
                               @RequestParam("Rname") String rname,
                               @RequestParam("Status") String status
) throws IOException {}
```

Comment: On an endpoint that it is expecting a file, you want to not send it. Is that okay? Why? I fail to understand the logic of your question, sorry. Maybe, are you asking about how to avoid sending the request if no file is selected? If so, Angular provide you with `Validators`. Or maybe, are you asking about how to send contents of file? If so, read the file on the backend or read on client and send stream to backend.

Comment: I mean, this service, can gives sending file. And in backend, controller waits 4 param. One of this param, it is fail. But if I don't send file, backend gives exception, and says null. And how can I send to RequestParam withoud exception, or how can I send 3 params. If I don't send file, backend gives exception

Comment: Oh, I get it. You want optional params. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the params expected to be null as **optional** on your Spring declaration.

#### Angular

I recommend checking if the file exists or is selected, so you do not send to the backend.

```js
const data: FormData = new FormData();
if ( file != null /* or whatever clause you want to test that the file exists or not */ ) {
  data.set('file', file);
}
```

#### Spring Backend

Indicate that param is optional. Depending on your Spring and Java version, the impelmentation may have variations.

```java
// In case of Java < 8, try this
@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,

// In case of Java > 8, try this
@RequestParam("file") Optional<MultipartFile> file,
```